# Show communities spinner (in Napili) via custom lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, napili, lightning-community

When you change pages in the Napili template, there's a spinner that displays. It's a white rectangular box with three animated dots.  Is there an event I can fire through a lightning component that will display that spinner, or some other way of displaying the spinner?

Note: looking through the auradocs documentation doesn't seem to indicate there is a standard event for displaying the spinner.
[image]

Comment: If you can't find a way to re-use the standard platform one (which is obviously a better way to go), the CSS is fairly simple to create your own. I use the CSS from http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/ for a 3 dot spinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by running your own JavaScript function (from within the controller / helper of a component) when you wish to trigger the event.

To show the spinner, you can use:
`document.querySelector('.siteforceSpinnerManager.siteforcePanelsContainer').classList.remove('hideEl')`

and to hide it again, you can use:
`document.querySelector('.siteforceSpinnerManager.siteforcePanelsContainer').classList.add('hideEl')`

Comment: Not ideal, but it's the only available solution other than rolling your own spinner or using lightning:spinner.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a component for the spinner and render only when you want, with something like a flag or even a event and hanlde with js.

```
<aura:attribute name="toggleSpinner" type="boolean" default="true"/>

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.toggleSpinner}">
      <c:mySpinner/>
</aura:if>
```

You can check this section of LDS if you want more info

[Spinners](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/spinners/)

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be achieved in the standard way so you can also create your own custom component for this and use that component in your page.